# Can zend's lucene implementation be configured to use a mysql database instead of the file system?

Tags: php, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Is there an option for Zend's lucene implementation (or a third-party plugin) that would allow me to put the lucene dictionary into a [MySQL] database?

The reason I need to ask is that the database is the only common resource for our two otherwise independent web servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are interfaces that could be implemented, I didn't find any readily available plugin. We will switch to another implementation, I'm currently evaluating [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).